# Excel sheet Cell with error message not cleared after mistake corrected

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel worksheet which in column N totals the values for each row from 17-30 for the preceding columns (B-M). In Row 30 it totals the columns from row 16 - 29

I want to write VBA code that every time a change is made to the sheet, will compare the total of N16:N29 and the total of B30:M30 and if the two values do not match will display a message in red font in cell N31 that states: "the totals for column N and row 30 do not match"

I wrote this code:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim totalN As Double
    Dim totalBToM As Double
        
        
    ' Check if the change was made in the range B30:M30 or N16:N29
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B30:M30,N16:N29")) Is Nothing Then
        ' Calculate the total for N16:N29
        totalN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("N16:N29"))
        ' Calculate the total for B30:M30
        totalBToM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B30:M30"))
        
        ' Compare the totals
        If totalN <> totalBToM Then
            ' Totals don't match, display the message in N31
            Range("N31").Value = "The totals for column N and row 30 do not match"
            Range("N31").Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0) ' Red font color
        Else
            ' Totals match, clear the message in N31 and reset the font color
            Range("N31").Clear

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I tested the code by making a change in a value in either the N Column or Row 30. In both cases the error message appears when I create a mistake. However, when I fix the mistake cell N31 is not cleared (the error message remains).

In case it is relevant: the values in both Column N and Row 30 are produced by formula's.

Why is cell N31 not cleared when the totals match again (after I corrected the mistake that produced the error message?

Comment: Note that the `Worksheet.Change` event doesn't fire when formulas recalculate. For that, you need the `Worksheet.Calculate` event.

Comment: Thanks. To bring about the error message I  change the formula in cell N23 from :  =SUM(B23:M23)   to =SUM(B23:D23). This causes the the VBA code to run and the error message appears. But when I change it back to =SUM(B23:M23) the error message remains.

Also, I added to the code that if the change happens within the range to open a message box to say "I noticed the change". The message box both appeared when I changed the formula in a cell in column N and when I changed it back. So when I change it back it appears the vba code is triggered.

Comment: If the values in column N and Row 30 are produced by formulas, then this event will not fire if their values change. Changing the formula itself will cause the change event to fire. If the formula's *value* changes though due to recalculation, the change event will not fire.

Comment: I added to the code two messageboxes to appear: if the values do not match a messagebox come up that says: "the values do not match", if the two values match the message box comes up: "the values do match). When I create an error the right box appears, but when I correct the error the box appears that still says "the values do not match"; however, they do (when I add the SUM N16:30 and B30:M30 I get the same value.

Comment: Probably need to `WorksheetFunction.Round` before comparing.

Comment: Wouldn't this be easier just using a worksheet formula?

Comment: Yes. When I changed 
'totalN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("N16:N29"))'  
to 
'Round(totalN = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("N16:N29")), 0) 
and 
'totalBToM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B30:M30"))' 
to 
'Round(totalBToM = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Range("B30:M30")), 0)'  
it solved the problem.

Thanks!